# hibernate.cfg.xml does not find hibernate.properties file

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

We used to have the hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate.properties files in the same folder in our  Java source folder. Now I moved the hibernate.properties file to another location. How can I make the hibernate.cfg.xml file find the hibernate.properties file again? I get an error which seems to indicate that it is not found anymore.

Comment: You can create configuration programmatically and manually pass any property file as hibernate.property, as described  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic

Comment: or, if you're using Spring http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?11462-Specifying-the-hibernate-properties-file-in-applicationConte

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Programmatically, you can load XML and properties like this:

```
public class MyHibernate {

  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        URL r1 = MyHibernate.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        Configuration c = new Configuration().configure(r1);

        try {
            InputStream is = MyHibernate.class.getResourceAsStream("/hibernate.properties");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(is);
            c.addProperties(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error reading properties", e);
        }

        return c.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        LOG.error("Error creating SessionFactory", ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

Hope it be useful.